# Fake homescreen loading every 60 seconds on an S3! How to stop it?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

[image: o]It started two days ago when my S3 on 4.1 would make noises and then a fake "homescreen" (which has functioning shorcuts! <--- how is that possible?) would popup every 60 seconds and sometimes every 2 min. In the middle of using other apps it just pops on tbe screen. I haven't done any updates or anything but I  have been trying some free software off Google Play but I'm sure I have uninstalled all of those...so first the  popup homescreen which is not what my real homescreen looked like it was Accuweather related so checked "active applications" and tried to delete every weather related thing but I couldn't find anything Accuweather related...here is a photo of the popup screen which is not my real screen:.... can you see the photo? (the pic is above the post now lol)...so I tried playing with the wallpaper settings etc. nothing is working.  Is it a virus?  Any tips? And, when I press my home button the fake screen shows up and I can't click on my real homescreen.  I just keep having to press the grey x on the fake screen to get back to normal....but then it sometimes comes back up seconds later.

Edit: Gotten worse now...every single time I try to get to my homescreen it goes to the screen in the attached photo so I can't open new apps, make calls...

Edit 2.0: so somehow it looks related to the docking function?  I unchecked every setting related to docking, homescreens etc. but of course when I press settings from my real screen it only affects my real screen...when the fake screen pops up it has a settings option but I'm so lost why I have two screens.  I have also never ever used the dock feature on tbe phone ever.

OS: 4.1

Comment: Can you get to the settings from the notification tray and force-stop it?

Comment: DanHulme I'm not sure what you mean...I don't see it as an active application...